# c2143, c4430 errors no clue why

Tags: c++

I will dive straight into the code. I am getting

> "error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

and

> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int

Here is how I have my header files defined as I think there is some problem with the header file declaration itself. I am getting the error in my Source.h file on the line where I declare my player object pointer -
**CPlayer* myplayer**

Firstly,

> **Headers.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
```

**GameSetup.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Headers.h"

class CGameSetup
{
public:
    CGameSetup(bool* _running,int ScreenWidth, int ScreenHeight);
    ~CGameSetup(void);

    SDL_Window* GetWindow();
    SDL_Renderer* GetRenderer();

    void Begin();
    void End();

private:
    SDL_Window* _screen;
    SDL_Renderer* _renderer;
};
```

**Source.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Headers.h"
#include "GameSetup.h"
#include "Sprite.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "Player.h"

class CSource
{
public:
    CSource(int ScreenWidth,int ScreenHeight);
    ~CSource(void);
    void GameLoop();
    CSprite* getPlayerSpriteReference();
    SDL_Event getEventHandler();
    int getMouseX();
    int getMouseY();

private:
    bool _running;
    CPlayer* myplayer;  // THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING THE TWO ERRORS ON**
    SDL_Event events;
    CGameSetup* gameSetup;
    CSprite* backgroundSprite;  
    int Mouse_X;
    int Mouse_Y;
    void Draw();
    void Update();
};
```

**Player.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Source.h"

namespace playerStates {
    enum States {down=1,up,left,right,standing};
}

class CPlayer
{
public:
    CPlayer(CGameSetup* gameSetup, int* p_MouseX, int* p_MouseY);
    ~CPlayer(void);
    void playerMove();
    void drawPlayerSprite();
    CSprite* getPlayerSpriteReference();

private:
    CSprite* playerSprite;
    CGameSetup* gSetup;
    SDL_Event events;
    int* Mouse_X;
    int* Mouse_Y;
    int* newMousePos_X;
    int* newMousePos_Y;
    int currentTime;
    bool movePlayer;
    float GetDistance(float x1,float y1,float x2,float y2);
    void SetPlayerState(int type);
};
```

Those are the 4 header files I have. Could someone please tell me if there is any problem in declared the include header files or are these errors related to something else which I am having a hard time troubleshooting!

Comment: Looks like a circular include issue.  Source.h and Player.h include each other.

Comment: Yep, 100% circular dependency issue.

Comment: But isn't that why we use #pragma once so that we get rid of the circular issue.

Comment: If I comment out all the declarations of player class in my source file then the errors are gone.

Comment: No, ``pragma once`` (which is non-standard by the way) is simply an *include guard*. It stops multiple copies of the header from being included into the same source file.

Comment: @JimZilla of course, because then there's nothing to actually cause the compiler to need to try and resolve the circular dependency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolve circular dependencies in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whats happening here is your compiler is going into `Player.h` marking it as "don't go back in here for this parse tree" and then encountering `Source.h`.

In `Source.h` you include `Player.h` **but** the compiler has already marked `Player.h` as "do not come back here" so it gets skipped.
When the line `CPlayer* myplayer;` is hit, the compiler has no idea what `CPlayer` is and throws a type error because it assumes that it is a name with a default `int` type.

The parse tree would look like (simplified):

```
CPlayer.h
 -- Source.h
  -- Cplayer.h -- Skipped, #pragma once
```

Resolving the circular dependency will fix the problem for you.

Comment: So what I did was I changed my player.h by removing source.h and adding gamesetup.h and sprite.h. That resolved the issue. How else could I have solved this issue?

Comment: @JimZilla you can use *forward declarations*. Since `Source.h` actually doesn't need to know anything about `CPlayer` other than the fact that it exists and it is a `class`, you could write: `class CPlayer;` in `Source.h` to announce this info.

Comment: You did the right thing. Re factoring your code until there is no cyclic dependency is the only way to get rid of them. As Matt says forward declarations help a lot too.